# Chemistry.SE is now in public beta!

Tags: discussion

Just a quick word to let you know that [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) has now launched into public beta. We welcome computational chemistry questions there too, so the boundary between the two sites is something we will have to figure out somewhat. We currently have a nice core of computation chemistry users on board (including myself) so those of you in that field my want to visit sometime!

Comment: congrats!  Feel free to ping any of the moderators here if you'd like to have a chat about cross-posting and migration.